# gimp and libreoffice crashes X

Tags: unity, 20.04, xorg, snap, gimp

When I start `gimp` I get these errors

```
$ gimp
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
Gtk-Message: 10:24:04.029: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 10:24:04.029: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 10:24:04.029: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 10:24:04.030: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
gimp_check_updates_callback: loading of https://gimp.org/gimp_versions.json failed: Operation not supported
```

When I then open a file, it dislays, but when I move the mouse, my desktop goes black and I get a new login screen.

I'm running `unity`, `ubuntu` display manager does not work, it just goes black.

I have a suspicion on snap and apparmor, as the first I see in the syslog after starting `gimp` is this

```
Aug 16 10:19:26 kfc-XPS-15-9560 systemd[2128]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Aug 16 10:19:26 kfc-XPS-15-9560 systemd[2128]: Started VTE child process 5769 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 5761.
Aug 16 10:19:27 kfc-XPS-15-9560 zeitgeist-datah[5789]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
Aug 16 10:19:31 kfc-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  138.211911] kauditd_printk_skb: 4493 callbacks suppressed
Aug 16 10:19:31 kfc-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  138.211912] audit: type=1400 audit(1597565971.209:12108): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/snap/core/9804/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0" pid=5806 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug 16 10:19:31 kfc-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  138.211946] audit: type=1400 audit(1597565971.209:12109): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/snap/core/9804/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0" pid=5806 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug 16 10:19:31 kfc-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  138.211996] audit: type=1400 audit(1597565971.209:12110): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/snap/core/9804/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0" pid=5806 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug 16 10:19:31 kfc-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  138.582372] audit: type=1326 audit(1597565971.581:12111): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=5806 comm="gimp" exe="/snap/gimp/292/usr/bin/gimp-2.10" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7f7c33ed0527 code=0x50000
Aug 16 10:19:31 kfc-XPS-15-9560 hud-service[5221]: #033[31mvoid DBusMenuImporter::slotGetLayoutFinished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)#033[0m: "No such interface â<80><9c>com.canonical.dbusmenuâ<80><9d> on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/window/41943043"
```

I have tried to disable `apparmor` but I still gets DENIED in the syslog

```
systemctl disable apparmor.service
```

I have similar errors with `libreoffice` draw, just start it and try to draw a rectangle crashes the desktop.
Also when I open a PDF file generated from Autocad, which contains a lot of small elements. In this case the mouse simply gets inactive, but I can still do operations with the keyboard.

Thus the error could also be in Xorg or even the nvidia drivers.

My system is a 19.10 upgraded to 20.04.1

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: The default libreoffice is an apt package. Are you using the snap package instead?

Comment: It is hard to say where ubuntu gets is default software from. The path is /usr/bin/libreoffice, thus I guess it is apt.